# Как стилизовать загружаемый контент iframe?

Tags: html, jquery, css, iframe

Есть скрипт, модуль оплаты, он загружается с удалённого сервера, оттуда же и подгружается файл стилей.
Всё содержимое находится в iframe. Как стилизовать это содержимое? Через мой (локальный) файл стилей не получается это сделать. Он мои стили просто не видит, хотя даю их нужным классам.

Answer (score 1):

Если iframe подгружается с вашего сайта, то можно поменять стили в нем через скрипт, например:

```
$('iframeSelector').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find('elementSelector').css('styleName','styleValue');
});
```

Если iframe с другого сайта, то никак не получится [policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)